# Prove and element must be the identity element?

Tags: abstract-algebra

The question is Prove: If $G$ is a group, a is in $G$ and the operation of $a*b=b$ (not multiplication, the $*$ stands for the operation) for some $b$ in $G$, then $a$ is the identity element of $G$. I don't understand why just because an element acted as the identity element one time it would be have to the identity element for the whole set?

Comment: In other words, the theorem is that in a group if there is an element a that is the identity for any particular element, then it's the identity element for all elements. Why? There's the symbolic proof, which may suffice, but do you want to know the _meaning_?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $b^{-1}$ the inverse of $b$ and $e$ the identity element then

$$a*b=b\implies a*b*b^{-1}=b*b^{-1}\implies a=a*e=e$$

Answer (score 2):

$G$ being a group any element is invertible so we can multiply the equality above with $b^{-1}$ to the right...